# How many words to highlight before or/and after matched text

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible with elasticsearch to configure the number of words before and after matched text?
Say for example I am searching for a keyword 'report' and set wordaround=5
Then it should return only 5 words containing the matched keyword

Please help me!!!

Comment: I tried boundary_max_size but it doesn't give the result I expected:(

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your fragment_size

See: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/highlighting.html

Comment: I tried fragment_size but didn't understand it fully . when I set fragment_size to 20 I got 'report' as content and ' report and found that my' when set to 25 . Can you give some explanation on what fragment_size does?? Appreciate your help

Comment: Could you post a full curl recreation? It's hard to understand what you are trying to do and how.